# Failed opening required file

Tags: php

I am getting the following error while running the code,

> Warning: require_once(product.php) [function.require-once]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pro\application\modules\products\controllers\test1.php
>   on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'product.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pro\application\modules\products\controllers\test1.php
>   on line 2

The code is simple,

```
<?php 
require_once "product.php";

    $array = "I am Fahad and I am testing this code";     
    $start = 4;
    $limit = 9;
    $value =  limit($array, $start, $limit);
    echo $value;
?>
```

The file `product.php` lies in the same directory as of the file which I am running. It still is giving an error. Please help out. Thanks

Comment: You say *The file product.php lies in the same directory as of the file which I am running*. The file you are running is itself included by another? If yes, require search for it in the same directory as *includer*.

Comment: So `C:\xampp\htdocs\pro\application\modules\products\controllers\product.php` is the location of the file correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The actual current directory is not *always* the same than the script you are running, especially inside a *framework* like you seem to use right now.

To make sure this is working, use

`require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/product.php';`

on 5.3, you can even say :

`require_once __DIR__ . '/product.php';`

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Check your filenames, especially case sensitivity (product.php != Product.php).

Answer (score 0):

The error is simple, it can't find the file "product.php" in the place its currently looking.

Personally I would never trust the script to know where to look automatically, I would always try and give absolute paths. For example:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/somedir/anotherdir/product.php';
```

Comment: **Never trust $_SERVER**! Use `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: Never is a very strong word, surely it depends on your server configuration and in what context you are using it?

Comment: @AdamThornton Yes, it depends on server configuration and it's completetly unsetted when you run the script from CLI (and it's not a edge case, I'm thinking about cronjobs)...

Comment: @Adam, never is the only safe way. Whatever you are doing - you can do it without *trusting* (or directly using) $_SERVER. If you must use it make sure to filter it.